# Is vmalloc() allocate bytes of memory which is virtually contiguous maps to memory area from different physical pages?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management

`vmalloc(size)` allocates a memory of `size` long which is virtually contiguous but the physical mapping would not be contiguous. Does that mean the the virtually allocated `size` long memory actually lies in different page frames of physical memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means just exactly that.